# Is this integral wrong?

Tags: integration, solution-verification

$$ \int(x^2+1)(x+1)dx$$

Per partes, let
$$u = x+1; u' = 1 $$
$$v' = x^2+1; v = x^3/3 + x $$

$$=(x+1)(x^3/3+x) - \int1*(x^3/3+x) = (x+1)(x^3/3+x) - \frac{1}{3}\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2} + C $$

Wolfram gave me this [$x^4/4+x^3/3+x^2/2+x+C$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%28x%5E2%20%2b%201%29%28x%20%2b%201%29dx). I understand it, but I would like to know if my solution is right too?
(Will I get points for my solution on exam? I know it depends on professor, but does my solution contain any essential mistake?)

EDIT: sorry for bad sign, I have badly rewritten it from papers

Comment: You have the wrong sign after integrating $\frac{x^3}{3}$ it should be a minus.

Comment: right answer, but you can remove braces at first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this a lot harder than it needs to be.  Just use the distributive property to expand it out into a polynomial.  That is:

$$(x^2 + 1)(x + 1)=x^3+x^2+x+1$$

If you are masochist, however, integration by parts works too. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one little mistake in the end. It should be $-\frac{1}{3}\frac{x^4}{4}$. From there one you can easily check that it gives the same answer;)

Comment: yeah, I had it like that, just badly rewritten ... so there is no essential mistake :)

Comment: No there isn't;)